# Navigation menu in jquery,php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a leftmenu showing items and tab content on the rightmenu.

When I click on Wingardium or its childnodes(leftmenu), the content should be shown inside the wingardium tab on the right menu..likewise

When I click on Data streams or its childnodes(leftmenu), the content should be shown inside the Data streams tab on the right menu..likewise

But in my code, the content is showing only inside the wingardium tab rather other tab on the rightmenu. Here is my code.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="js/jqueryv1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    //--LEFT MENU SCRIPT--//
    $ (document).ready(function()
    {
       $ (".wings").click(function(event)
       {
         $(".box").slideUp("slow");
         if ($(this).next().is(":hidden") == true)
         {
           $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
         }
       });
       //(".box").hide("slow");
    });

    //--RIGHT_MENU TAB SCRIPT----//
    $ (document).ready(function() 
    {    
      $('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
      $('.container').hide();
      $('.container:first').show();

      $('#tabs li a').click(function()
      {
        var t = $(this).attr('id');
        if($(this).hasClass('inactive'))
        { //this is the start of our condition 
          $('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');         
          $(this).removeClass('inactive');
          $('.container').hide();
          $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
        }
     });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    ol#menu {  margin:0px 10px; padding:0;  text-align:left; }
    ol#menu li { position:relative; list-style-type:none; border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;  padding:7px 0;}
    ol#menu .current { border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;}
    ol#menu li:hover { border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;}
    ol#menu li a { padding:0px 0px; text-decoration:none; color:#68759c;}  
    ol#menu li a:hover { color:#8895b8; border:none; }

    .wings { width:200px; float:left; padding:0px 0px; }
    .box { width:195px; /* display:none;*/ margin:14px 0px; }

    #tabs { width:100%; height:30px; border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; padding-right:2px; margin-top:10px; }
    #tabs li { float:left;  list-style:none;  border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc; margin-right:5px; 
               border-top-left-radius:3px; border-top-right-radius:3px; outline:none; }
    #tabs li a { font-family:calibri; font-size:15px; color:#5685bc; padding-top:5px; padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:8px; 
                 display:block; 
             background: #FFF; border-top-left-radius:3px;  border-top-right-radius:3px; text-decoration:none; outline:none; }
    #tabs li a.inactive { padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-right:8px; color:#666666; background:#EEE; outline:none;
                      border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; } 
    #tabs li a:hover, #tabs li a.inactive:hover { color:#5685bc; outline:none; }

    .container { clear:both; width:99%; border:0px solid #CCC; padding-top:2px; margin:0 auto; }  
    .container ul { margin-left:25px; font-size:small; line-height:1.4; list-style-type:disc; }
    .container li { padding-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="float:left;width:200px;border:1px solid lightgray;margin:0px 23px;"><!--leftmenu-->
    <ol id="menu">
     <li>
        <a href="home.php#" id="ds1">Wingardium</a>
        <img class="wings" src="images/downarrow.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;cursor:pointer;float:right;"/>
        <div class="box" style="margin:6px 0px;">
          <a href="#">Wingardium1</a><br>
          <a href="#">Wingardium2</a>
        </div>
     </li>

     <li>
        <a href="home.php#" id="ds2">Data streams</a>
        <img class="wings" src="images/downarrow.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;cursor:pointer;float:right;"/>
        <div class="box" style="margin:6px 0px;">
          <a href="#">Stream1</a><br>
          <a href="#">Stream2</a>
        </div>
     </li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;width:800px;border:1px solid lightgray;margin:0px 23px;"><!--rightmenu-->
    <ul id="tabs">
       <li><a id="tab1">Wingardium</a></li>   
       <li><a id="tab2">Data streams </a></li>        
    </ul>
    <div class="container" id="tab1C">Wingardium content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab2C">Data streams content</div>   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

UPDATED CODE

Here I have links given for childnodes in the leftmenu. Now when I click on childnodes, it should display a different echo message, but that wasn't happening

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="js/jqueryv1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    $ (document).ready(function()
    {
       $ (".wings").click(function(event)
       {
         $(".box").slideUp("slow");
         if ($(this).next().is(":hidden") == true)
         {
           $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
         }
         return false;
       });

       $('#menu li').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           ind = $(this).index()

           if(ind == 0)
           $('#tabs li:first').click()
           else
           $('#tabs li:eq(1)').click();

           return false;
           })
       //(".box").hide("slow");
    });

    //--RIGHT_MENU TAB SCRIPT----//
    $ (document).ready(function() 
    {    
      $('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
      $('.container').hide();
      $('.container:first').show();

      $('#tabs li').click(function()
      {
        var t = $('a',this).attr('id');
        if($('a',this).hasClass('inactive'))
        { //this is the start of our condition 
          $('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');         
          $('a',this).removeClass('inactive');
          $('.container').hide();
          $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
        }
        return false;
     });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    ol#menu {  margin:0px 10px; padding:0;  text-align:left; }
    ol#menu li { position:relative; list-style-type:none; border-bottom:1px solid #efefef; padding:7px 0;}
    ol#menu .current { border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;}
    ol#menu li:hover { border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;}
    ol#menu li a { padding:0px 0px; text-decoration:none; color:#68759c;}  
    ol#menu li a:hover { color:#8895b8; border:none; }

    .wings { width:200px; float:left; padding:0px 0px; }
    .box { width:195px; /* display:none;*/ margin:14px 0px; }

    #tabs { width:100%; height:30px; border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; padding-right:2px; margin-top:10px; }
    #tabs li { float:left;  list-style:none;  border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc; margin-right:5px; 
               border-top-left-radius:3px; border-top-right-radius:3px; outline:none; }
    #tabs li a { font-family:calibri; font-size:15px; color:#5685bc; padding-top:5px; padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:8px; 
                 display:block; 
             background: #FFF; border-top-left-radius:3px;  border-top-right-radius:3px; text-decoration:none; outline:none; }
    #tabs li a.inactive { padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-right:8px; color:#666666; background:#EEE; outline:none;
                      border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; } 
    #tabs li a:hover, #tabs li a.inactive:hover { color:#5685bc; outline:none; }

    .container { clear:both; width:99%; border:0px solid #CCC; padding-top:2px; margin:0 auto; }  
    .container ul { margin-left:25px; font-size:small; line-height:1.4; list-style-type:disc; }
    .container li { padding-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="float:left;width:200px;border:1px solid lightgray;margin:0px 23px;"><!--leftmenu-->
    <ol id="menu">
     <li>
        <a href="home.php#" id="ds1">Wingardium</a>
        <img class="wings" src="images/downarrow.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;cursor:pointer;float:right;"/>
        <div class="box" style="margin:6px 0px;">
          <a href="home.php?id=1">Wingardium1</a><br>
          <a href="home.php?id=2">Wingardium2</a>
        </div>
     </li>

     <li>
        <a href="home.php#" id="ds2">Data streams</a>
        <img class="wings" src="images/downarrow.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;cursor:pointer;float:right;"/>
        <div class="box" style="margin:6px 0px;">
          <a href="home.php?id=1">Stream1</a><br>
          <a href="home.php?id=2">Stream2</a>
        </div>
     </li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;width:800px;border:1px solid lightgray;margin:0px 23px;"><!--rightmenu-->
    <ul id="tabs">
       <li><a id="tab1">Wingardium</a></li>   
       <li><a id="tab2">Data streams </a></li>        
    </ul>
    <div class="container" id="tab1C">Wingardium content
      <?php
         if (isset($_GET["id"]))  
         echo 'there is id';
         else
         echo 'normal content';
       ?>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="tab2C">Data streams content
      <?php
         if (isset($_GET["id"]))  
         echo 'there is id';
         else
         echo 'normal content';
       ?>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 $ (document).ready(function()
    {
       $ (".wings").click(function(event)
       {
         $(".box").slideUp("slow");
         if ($(this).next().is(":hidden") == true)
         {
           $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
         }
         return false;
       });

       $('#menu li').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           ind = $(this).index()

           if(ind == 0)
           $('#tabs li:first').click()
           else
           $('#tabs li:eq(1)').click();

           return false;
           })
       //(".box").hide("slow");
    });

    //--RIGHT_MENU TAB SCRIPT----//
    $ (document).ready(function() 
    {    
      $('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
      $('.container').hide();
      $('.container:first').show();

      $('#tabs li').click(function()
      {
        var t = $('a',this).attr('id');
        if($('a',this).hasClass('inactive'))
        { //this is the start of our condition 
          $('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');         
          $('a',this).removeClass('inactive');
          $('.container').hide();
          $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
        }
        return false;
     });
    });
```

If you have problem still then place it in jsfiddle.

Comment: I have a slight change here... I have updated my code

Comment: Could you tell me why the links content weren't displaying

Comment: you had not written event for the menu click that's why content were not displaying

Comment: Do I need to write a js script like  "#menu li" for childnodes too

Comment: It depends on your requirement how and what do you want?

Comment: But I have a problem when I click childnodes, I wasn't getting the correct echo message..and even I have mentioned isset.

Comment: create JS fiddle for this... and send the link.. I will try to solve.

Comment: I have created JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/j5yh8/, but isset was used on rightmenu.. may be that mayn't work in fiddle or we can take in js syntax. Thank You in advance